# How to dynamically append fully compiled components to DOM in VueJS

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to make something like pop-up notifications.

- Each notification will be created async. (Random intervals)
- Each notification will be a component. `Eg. <my-notification ... />`
- Main component `<notification-manager />` should be able to create N notifications.

Comment: check this example out: https://codepen.io/getreworked/pen/XZOgbm?editors=1010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<template>
    <my-notification v-for="notification in notifications" :notification="notification" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data(){
        notifications: []
    },
    async created() {
        var notification = await getNotificaiton();
        this.notifications.push(notification);   
        // Keep on pushing as you get
    }
}
</script>
```